# Nginx configuration for clean urls

Tags: url, nginx, server, assets

I have a website with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── assets
├── config
├── html
├── spec
└── vendor
```

I'm using this as a development setup for running integration tests and I need a server instance. I need the site root to be in html but I need to be able to link to the assets in assets. So far this is what I have and it isn't working:

```
server {
    listen       9001;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/assets;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
    # ... all the comments in the default config
}
```

The pages are being served but it can't find any of the assets. It's looking here:

```
http://localhost:9001/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

***UPDATE***

You were right on your assumptions about the directory structure.
I changed the config to the following with the same results:

```
server {
    listen       9001;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    }

    location /assets/ {
        # I also tried using 'root' instead of 'alias' but same results
        alias /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/assets;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it a bit more I tried this and it worked.

```
server {
    listen       9001;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location /assets/ {
        root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www;
    }
}
```

I liked Dayo's answer a lot because after reading the documentation it seemed to me that an alias is better suited for what I'm doing, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: There is no material difference between both answers. Perhaps you mistyped something while trying to apply my suggestion. I note that your edited question leaves out the end slash of the alias path which for reasons I can no longer recollect, I always found necessary to be included.

Comment: I double checked everything. It doesn't work with `alias` but it works with `root`. I even tried adding the slash at the end of the alias path.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've set `root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www` which implies to me that the directory structure looks like this:

```
www
├── assets
├── config
├── html
├── spec
└── vendor
```

If that is correct, then perhaps you need to revise your assets location block to this (added `www`):

```
location /assets/ {
    root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/assets;
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer after I tried your solution. You were right about the overall directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have the www setup as Blake Frederick thinks, then you can look into the following:

```
server {
    listen 9001;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # The root and index directives should typically 
        # not be in locations blocks
        # Minimum really is the server block.
        # Usually even better in http block.
    }
    location /assets/ {
        # What you need here is the alias directive
        alias /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/assets/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but no results. I posted the update as an edit in the original question.